# How to deserialize array of different types from JSON

Tags: c#, json

I have JSON string that looks like:

```
{
    "type": "group",
    "logicalOperator": "or",
    "conditions":[{
            "type": "condition",
            "metric": "CTR",
            "operator": ">=",
            "value": "123"
        },
        {
            "type": "group",
            "logicalOperator": "and",
            "conditions": [{
                "type": "condition",
                "metric": "CTR",
                "operator": ">=",
                "value": "123"
                }]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to deserialize it into C# classes (using `Newtonsoft.JSON`). But the point that `conditions` can include `group` or `condition` make problem for me.

```
public class Group {
    public string logicalOperator { get; set; }
    public List<object> conditions { get; set; }
}

public class Condition {
    public string metric { get; set; }
    public string @operator { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}
```

How can I get rid of the `List<object>`? TIA!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON.NET - Conditional Type Deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816780/json-net-conditional-type-deserialization)

Comment: Please look at this, i have marked this as possible duplicate. Because your problem looks like conditional deserialization. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816780/json-net-conditional-type-deserialization

Comment: Assuming you can use [tag:json.net], take a look at [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/3744182) and [How to implement custom JsonConverter in JSON.NET to deserialize a List of base class objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8030538/3744182)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I turn a C# object into a JSON string in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/how-do-i-turn-a-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no issue:

```
public class YourType
{
    public ConditionType Type { get; set; }
    public string Metric { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string LogicalOperator { get; set; }

    public List<YourType> Conditions { get; set; }
}

public enum ConditionType
{
    Group,
    Condition
}
```

Then just deserialize it as normal

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourType>(yourJson);
```

You will end up with a single `YourType` class that has an enumerator `Type` that you can use to determine if its a group or condition.

If it is a condition, the properties are filled out.

If it is a group, your `Conditions` inner list contains the rest.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I thought about that variant. But i guess check properties for null to understend which class it is - a bad practies. Especcially when we talk about some language like C# (OOP)

Comment: You aren't checking for null. You are checking the Type enum property

Comment: Ah, yea. Miss that. Ok, ty.

Answer (score 0):

First of all C# doesn’t deserialize json strings. C# can be used to invoke libraries which do.

Based on pure guesses I would go ahead and say you’re maybe using `Newtonsoft.Json` to do the deserializing although you might very well be using something else. Let’s take a step back.

If that were the case, then “getting rid” of `List<object>` would be your smallest concern. Actually being able to come up with instances which aren’t just empty, plain’ol `System.Object` instances would be your first challenge. That’s simply because telling the deserializer what your super (base) type is won’t even make them go look for possible subtypes since the subtypes of any type is an open set (anyone can take and reference your assembly and extend your class without you feeling anything).

Having a list of references of type `System.Object` each pointing towards instancesof type `MyNamespace.Group` or `MyNamespace.Condition` might look like a drag until you realize that having instances of `MyNamespace.Group` and the other is the actual challenge in this particular use case you’re describing.

Taking another step back, in OOP, whenever you want to store a list of possibly different types of instances and your language is strongly typed and provides some sort of generics (C# is included), you cannot have a generic argument for element type which is not implicitly assignable from each and every one of the specific types you want your instances to potentially be. In your case, `object` is compatible with more than `Group` and `Condition`. If that is your sole problem then you should simply create a 3rd class (let’s call it `EitherGroupOrCondition`) and make that the root of a naturally occurring class hierarchy (both `Group` and `Condition` should now extend `EitherGroupOrCondition`). Then you could turn your `List<object>` into a `List<EitherGroupOrCondition>`.

Going back to deserializing: You would need to look at `JsonSerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling` and it’s entourage of features.

You should consider the following prerequisites to achieving your goal:

- understanding OOP thoroughly
- understanding your particular Json deserializer’s capabilities (hopefully you’re using `Newtonsoft.Json`)

Both of these prerequisites take time and patience and I encourage you to go ahead and fill them and never work blindly, without understanding at least the proposed product surface of that which you are using.